# What is this code autogenerated in my ReactJs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is this autogenerated code do to my ReactJs app?, and benefits of having it in my app.

```
    <div class="nsc-panel nsc-panel-compact nsc-hide">
        <div class="nsc-panel-move"></div>
            <div class="nsc-panel-tooltip">
                <div class="nsc-panel-tooltip-layout" layout="row" layout-align="start center">CTRL+V to toggle the panel</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </div>
```

Comment: that piece of code wasn't generated by ReactApp by default. It seems like your browser extension might have added them into the page. You can saftely remove if you don't need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and it was affecting my theme's page builder system. It's caused by the Nibus Screen Capture extension in Chrome ( nsc- ). Once I deactivated that extension it immediately disappeared.